# "On Behalf of" /Sender header for Emails

Tags: civimail

our setup does not allow us to change SPF records. Which is fine - but we would like to utilize the "On Behalf of" or "Via" by using a "Sender" mail header. This [forum post from 2015](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=36259.0) explains that CiviCRM does not have the "Sender" mail header - but is there any work on this?  Both [MailChimp](https://kb.mailchimp.com/accounts/email-authentication/my-campaign-from-name-shows-mcsvnet) and SalsaLabs have this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 99% sure there hasn't been any work on this.

Comment: then i will give you a +.99 on this ;-)

Comment: Well that sucks. :-/

Comment: If there's a hook that allows changing the mail headers, this would only be a few lines of code to implement as an extension.  Implementing a hook itself is only a few lines of code, so someone could conceivably write the hook, then the extension.